# ChartJS label font size is scaled up and squeezed together

Tags: node.js, azure, charts, chart.js, label

I have a nodejs app which is generating chartjs diagram images. In local the label is fine it looks like this: [image]

But when I deploy exactly the same code to azure it looks like the label is scaled up and jammed.
[image]

My dependencies are `"dependencies": { "chart.js": "2.7.3", "chartjs-node-canvas": "3.2.0"}` and this is my chart config:

```
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltips: {
                enabled: false
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 0
            },
            elements: {
                line: {
                    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
                }
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'linear',
                    display: true,
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: true,
                        fontColor: gray,
                        fontSize: 14,
                        maxRotation: 0,
                        min: 0,
                        minRotation: 0,
                        padding: 10
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'transparent',
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        drawTicks: false,
                        zeroLineColor: gray,
                        zeroLineWidth: 2
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: xLabel,
                        fontColor: gray,
                        fontSize: 14
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    id: this.yAxisId,
                    position: 'left',
                    ticks,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: transparentGray,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                        drawTicks: false,
                        zeroLineColor: gray,
                        zeroLineWidth: 2
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: yLabel,
                        fontColor: gray,
                        fontSize: 14
                    }
                }]
            }
```

Something is wrong with my options and then why it works perfectly fine on local?